# Loading Multiple Listbox Items to database

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with several listboxes, i wanted to know how to load the items in the listbox to my access database.

```
dim db as dao.database
dim rs as dao.recordset
dim strsql as string
dim item as variant    

set db = currentdb()

strsql = "SELECT * FROM TBL WHERE ID = '"& a & "'"

set rs = db.openrecordset(strsql)

for i = 0 to me.lst1.listcount -1)
    '"stuck here or I may be using the wrong code..."
next
```

any assistance is welcome...

Comment: Are you trying to update the record with ID of `a`? You say you have several listboxes. Is there one listbox for each field you want to update? Or are you concerned with just one of the listboxes? Please give an example, with some sample values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, your problem can be solved by something like this:

```
Sub Sample()

Dim ctl as Control
Dim idx As Long
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from MyTable")

    'Find each listbox control on the form, and get its contents
    For Each ctl In me.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acListBox Then
            'If it's a listbox, write the contents to a table
            For idx = 0 To ctl.ListCount - 1
                rec.AddNew
                rec("MyDataField") = ctl.ItemData(idx)
                rec.Update
            Next
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the code posted by JOhnny Bones you can add a check over the name if you want to track the source of data.

The property is ctl.Name

Bye,

Wiz